# Allow contributors to edit their own images

Tags: editor

We are trying to create a site in WordPress that will allow visitors to the site register and upload their own content and images.

I want them to be able to edit and delete their own images once they upload them but not access anyone else's.

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use WP Users Media plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-users-media/

From description:

> ... disable the ability for users to access other members files and
>   attachments through the Media Button and Featured Image sections...